# Node JS Express removed files throws an error: 'Cannot find module './jobs.resolver''

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, graphql

So I tried to remove some files for code cleanup and some normalization. However express then gives me an error of: "Cannot find module './jobs.resolver'" Which is one of the files I removed.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
 "name": "typegraphql-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "author": "Tom Nagle",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child --watch src src/index.ts",
    "start": "node ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^9.7.1",
    "apollo-server": "^3.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "graphql": "15.x",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.9",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.30",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/config": "^0.0.40",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the error stack:

Error: Cannot find module './jobs.resolver'

```
Require stack:
- B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\src\resolvers\index.ts
- B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\src\index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\src\resolvers\index.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module._compile (B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Bon\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-9024418715050684.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\Users\Bon\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-9024418715050684.js:71:20)
[ERROR] 20:56:46 Error: Cannot find module './jobs.resolver'
Require stack:
- B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\src\resolvers\index.ts
- B:\jrevsols\jrevsolsBE\src\index.ts
```

Not really sure why this is happening and searching the issue most of them are unreleated